# How to get the scroll position of a UITableView in real time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, contentoffset

I need to get the scroll position of a table view in real time.
What I am currently doing is:

```
func animationOffset() {
    let offset = tableView.contentOffset.y
}
```

This function is connected to a timer

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(TimelineViewController.animationOffset), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This code works fine if the user lifts their finger off the screen, but if they don't and keep scrolling, the offset will never be updated and my app will not run properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small gotcha - in Swift 3 it's

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

and the below is not going to be triggered :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can implement

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

of the `UITableViewDelegate` which is called when the scroll position of the tableview is changed and there you can use `tableView.contentOffset.y` to get scroll position.

Comment: Be careful with what you do in this method as it is called on every frame, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get **First** and **Last** **INDEX** of visible **UITableView** item by using function below

> This function also update itself every time when you scroll  (Real time)

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    //First Visible Item
    print(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first)

    //Last visible item
    print(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last)
}
```